# How do I get the value/text of a dropdown box that got inserted into a table row via JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table where the user can hit an "add" button, and once the user does this there will be a new row in the table. This is done via JQuery.

In each new row, one column has a dropdown box (with predefined values). How do I get the selected value of this dropdown box? The dropdown box will never exist on the page, unless added via the JQuery.

I want to change the value of the next column depending on the value of the dropbox. For instance, if the user selects dropdown box, a dropdown box will appear in the next column

To test if JavaScript/JQuery was working correctly etc, I displayed a silly alert message once the "add" button was hit. This worked successfully.

I have tried displaying another message once the value of the dropdown box changes etc, but I have been unsuccessful.

I guess my question is can I get the value of an element that doesn't exist on the DOM unless created dynamically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

My HTML:

```
<div id="etDiv">
    <table style="width:100%" border="dotted" class="createElementTable" id="table">
        <caption>
            <!-- To do -->
            <tr class="tableText">
                <th class="tableText">Required</th>
                <th class="tableText">Label</th>
                <th class="tableText">Type</th>
                <th class="tableText">Values</th>
                <th class="tableText">Decrease/Increase</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My JQuery:

```
$('#addButton').click(function () {
    count = count + 1;
    alert("Element: " + count + " added.");
    $required = "<input type='checkbox' name='check'>";
    $label = "<input type='text' placeholder='Enter your label'>    </input>";
    $type = "<SELECT name='type' onchange='typeCheck(this)'>    <>Type</option><OPTION value='header'>Header</option><OPTION     value='hr'>HR</option><OPTION value='textbox'>Text Box</option><OPTION     value='datefield'>Date Field</option><OPTION     value='person'>Person</option><OPTION value='dropdownbox'>Dropdown     Box</option><OPTION value='image'>Image</option><OPTION     value='checkboxgroup'>Checkbox Group</option><OPTION     value='radiogroup'>Radio Group</option><option>" + count + "</option>    </select>";
    $values = "To Do";
    $capacity = "To Do";
    $element = "<tr class='child'> <td>" + $required + "</td>     <td>" + $label + "</td> + <td>" + $type + "</td> <td>" + $values + "</td>     <td>" + $capacity + "</td>";

    $('#table tr:last').after($element);
});
```

I wish to get the value of $type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `onchange='typeCheck(this)'` and use the event delegation syntax of jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('table').on('change', 'select[name="type"]', function(){
    console.log($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Looking at the code/documentation, it should work but it isn't. Any suggestions on where I have went wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I had the event and selector in the wrong order. I've updated my answer. See https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sn38mL0m/

Comment: Ah thank you! 5 hours later and I've made progress, woohoo! My next question is: how do I add the value to a variable? var value = $(this).val(); doesn't seem to be working EDIT - it is working, perhaps I didn't save it before haha. Thank you though, much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById(this).value

Comment: in the onchange function this code should work perfectly

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried this code and it didn't work.'SELECT name='type' onchange='typeCheck()'and  function typeCheck()
 {
  alert("typeCheck() executed!");
  var value = document.getElementById(this).value;
  alert(value);
 }